# Why does np.linalg.solve raise Bus Error when running on its own Thread (Mac M1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyside6

Here is my configuration:
numpy: 1.6.2,
OS: macOs Monterey 12.2.1 (M1),
Python 3.10 (venv)

I am trying to run some numpy calculations with PySide GUI. Those can be heavy so I want them to run on their own thread.
But when I do this I have the following error:

`[1]    38918 bus error  python3 app.py`

Here is my PySide code:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, QThreadPool, QThread, QObject, Signal, QMetaObject
import numpy as np

from algorithm import main
from test_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = Signal(int)
    progress = Signal(tuple)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        np.linalg.solve(np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]]), np.array([[2,3], [3,4]]))
        print("a")
        self.finished.emit(1)

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run_ht)

        self.thread = None
        self.worker = None

        self.buildWorker()

    def run_ht(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def buildWorker(self):
        thread = QThread()
        worker = Worker()
        worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.started.connect(worker.run)
        worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
        self.thread = thread
        self.worker = worker


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

I don't want to put all my calculations code (and it would be too long I think) but after investigation I found that the error occurs with this line:

```py
U = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
```

If I run the same code without threading everythings works perfectly

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Besides, except for particular conditions, computations that are heavily CPU bound get almost no benefit from threading.

Comment: @musicamante Note that the OP certainly use threading so to avoid the GUI being frozen. Besides, AFAIK Numpy release the GIL for many optimized functions so it can actually be a bit faster. I strongly agree for the minimal working example though, especially since it is a low-level issue and it might only happen on the M1 processors. The best would be to remove the GUI part.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, I should've probably been more clear in that statement. The fact is, it's common for people, especially beginners, to believe that just using threading and numpy "automagically" *speeds up* things, or that they can put anything in the thread without thinking/knowing about the GIL (I know, I used to make the same mistake, as many of us). We don't know the experience of the OP, so, better safe than sorry ;-)

Comment: @musicamante like Jérôme Richard said, I use threading to avoid GUI to be frozen. I cannot remove the GUI part, It aims to be an Open Source software for non-developers (but there is maybe a better way to achieve this). I've edited my code with minimal reproducible exemple

Comment: @JérômeRichard the GUI removal is just for the sake of the question, to rule out any problem that might be related to the UI, while still using threading: macOS has a long story of inexplicable issues that are caused by things that shouldn't "intuitively" create problems. You could use a QCoreApplication along with a QTimer in the main thread to start the worker.

Comment: @musicamante oh okay I did not understand. Thanks I will try your idea

Comment: @musicamante So I used python threading instead of QThreading and everything worked perfectly, is there any difference between QT threading and python threading  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it, by running a new process from the Thread:

```py
class Worker(QThread):
    finished = Signal(float)
    progress = Signal(float)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.process = None
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        p = multiprocessing.Value('d', 0.0)
        t = multiprocessing.Value('d', 0.0)
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target = main, args=(p, t))
        self.process.start()
        while (p.value < 1.0) & self.running:
            self.progress.emit(p.value)
        self.process.join()
        self.finished.emit(t.value)

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        

        self.ui.run.clicked.connect(self.run_ht)

        self.thread = None

        self.build_worker()

    def run_ht(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def finished(self, time):
        self.thread.quit()

    def build_worker(self):
        self.thread = Worker()
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.finished)
```

Comment: Good, but this still doesn't rule out the possibility of a bug related to the macOS/M1 implementation.

Comment: @musicamante yeah that's true, I will try my old code on a VM when I will have some free time, I will post there the result

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here on a M2 machine. Quick fix:

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that many numpy functions release the global interpreter lock (GIL) and then call underlying blas routines which will attempt to use multiple pthreads from the underlying operating system. This then causes weird crashes with bus errors etc. as those multiple pthreads clobber each other's objects.

An elegant solution is to use the threadpoolctl library to explicitly limit at runtime the number of threads the blas libraries employ to 1.

See https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl

This does not require setting a global environment variable and can be done just for the portions of code required.